# My first code doesn't work, the second does but they're almost the same. How to find ther reason of the black thumbnails?

Tags: php, image, http-headers, gd, thumbnails

This is the first code. The saved thumbnail is in the folder, the file type is perfect, the size is perfect,but the thumbnails are BLACK.

As I see, the problem is near here:  `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` Before this line, everything is OK.

```
if (isset($_POST['rendben'])) {

    $tipusok = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
    $bejovonev=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['nev'])));

    if (in_array($_FILES['kep']['type'], $tipusok) && $_FILES['kep']['size'] < 2000000 && (!empty($bejovonev)) ) {

        switch ($_FILES['kep']['type']) {
            case "image/jpeg": $kiterjesztes = ".jpg"; break;
            case "image/gif":  $kiterjesztes = ".gif"; break;
            case "image/png":  $kiterjesztes = ".png"; break;
        }

        $nev = ekezettelenito($bejovonev);

        $eredeti    = $_FILES['kep']['name'];
        $ideiglenes = $_FILES['kep']['tmp_name'];
        $tipus      = $_FILES['kep']['type'];
        $hiba       = $_FILES['kep']['error'];
        $meret      = $_FILES['kep']['size'];

        $kimenet = "<p>A fájl tulajdonságai:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>név: {$nev}</li>
            <li>típus: {$tipus}</li>
            <li>ideiglenes név: {$ideiglenes}</li>
            <li>hiba száma: {$hiba}</li>
            <li>mérete: ".round($meret/1024)." KByte</li>
        </ul>\n";
        move_uploaded_file($ideiglenes, "../kepek/nagykepek/{$nev}.{$kiterjesztes}");

        //Thumbnails

        $new=142;
        $picture="../kepek/nagykepek/{$nev}{$kiterjesztes}";

            switch ($kiterjesztes) {
            case ".jpg": $orig=imagecreatefromjpeg($picture); break;
            case ".gif":  $orig=imagecreatefromgif($picture); break;
            case ".png":  $orig=imagecreatefrompng($picture); break;
        }

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($picture);
        $crop= ($width>$height) ? $height: $width; 
        $dest= imagecreatetruecolor($new,$new);
        imagecopyresampled($dest, $orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new, $new, $crop, $crop);

        switch ($kiterjesztes) {
            case ".jpg": header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); break;
            case ".gif": header('Content-Type: image/gif'); break;
            case ".png": header('Content-Type: image/png'); break;
        }
        switch ($kiterjesztes) {
            case ".jpg": imagejpeg($dest,"../kepek/kiskepek/{$nev}{$kiterjesztes}"); break;
            case ".gif": imagegif($dest,"../kepek/kiskepek/{$nev}{$kiterjesztes}"); break;
            case ".png": imagepng($dest,"../kepek/kiskepek/{$nev}{$kiterjesztes}"); break;
        }

    }
    else {
        $kimenet = "<p><em>Érvénytelen fájlformátum vagy fájlnév!</em></p>\n";
    }
}

//Output

$konyvtar = "../kepek/kiskepek/";
$tartalom = scandir($konyvtar);
$tipusok  = array(".jpg", ".gif", ".png");
$kepek    = "";

foreach ($tartalom as $fajl) {
    if (in_array(substr($fajl, -4), $tipusok)) {
        $kepek.= "<img src=\"{$konyvtar}{$fajl}\" alt=\"{$fajl}\" />\n";
    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($kimenet)) print $kimenet; ?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Név:<br />
    <input type="text" id="nev" name="nev" /></p>
    <p>Kép:<br />
    <input type="file" id="kep" name="kep" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" id="rendben" name="rendben" value="Rendben" />
    </p>
</form>
<?php print $kepek; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my second code. It works with all the three image types.

```
<?php  

//$nev="asd2.jpg";  
//$nev="asd2.png";  
$nev="asd2.gif";  

$new=142;  

//$picture="111.jpg";  
//$picture="asdasd.png";  
$picture="xx.gif";  

//$orig=imagecreatefromjpeg($picture);  
//$orig=imagecreatefrompng($picture);  
$orig=imagecreatefromgif($picture);  

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($picture);  

$crop= ($width>$height) ? $height: $width;   

$dest= imagecreatetruecolor($new,$new);  

imagecopyresampled($dest, $orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new, $new, $crop, $crop);  

//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  
//header('Content-Type: image/png');  
header('Content-Type: image/gif');  

imagejpeg($dest,"../kepek/kiskepek/{$nev}");  

?>
```

I really don't know where the problem is. How can I find it? I tried print, print_r, var_dump, but everything seems normal.

Comment: In the title you say the first block of code works. In the question you say that the second block of code works. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you. The second works, the first doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

did you fix your problem?
if not, you may check here:

in this line, you save the image with some name

```
move_uploaded_file($ideiglenes, "../kepek/nagykepek/{$nev}.{$kiterjesztes}");
                                                          ^  //important
```

and the name, would be something like

```
 nameimg..jpg
         ^
```

and, you use this line to call the image:

```
$picture="../kepek/nagykepek/{$nev}{$kiterjesztes}";
                                   ^  //no dot here
```

the last line call a image

```
 nameimg.jpg
```

so, you should get some error messages, or if you disabled to show them you will get black images...

Comment: I fixed it, but the problem was the header. I still don't know what was the problem with it, but I deleted the header lines and it worked. Later I noticed the 2 dots,but they weren't a problem, because the first dot was the last character of the image name. Anyway I corrected it, but thank you :)